# Php last time online

Tags: php

I am building website using php and i want to show information about last time online on my website for every user
.It is easy to say when user opened any page of my website, but is it possible to say when user closed my website , for example he entered my website's article at 2.30 and have been reading it for 5 minutes and closed my website. So the time of last time online should be 2.35,  but not 2.30.Is it possible to add session expired event or page close event? Or is there any other solution of this problem?

Comment: I think functions to do it exist, but if you want you could make an Ajax call every few seconds that update the last access time

Comment: It is not easy to define what is "have been reading it"... What if a user opened an article and then just left the PC open? You use some kind of idle timer or events, but that will not solve all the cases.

Comment: Sessions doesn't work like that. Sessions are stored on the server and doesn't know anything about what happens in the client. The client just stores a session id in a cookie which it passes along with the requests from the client to the server to identify the session. The session data itself (on the server) doesn't get destroyed/removed when the session ends in the browser. It's a garbage collector on the server that removes session data if it's been inactive (haven't been used) for x amount of time.

Comment: I would just store the time for each request to the server (page load, ajax request or what not). If the time then diffs a minute here or there, does it really matter? Sending requests to the server every minute to update the time would give you a more accurate time, but it would also increase the server load so the question is if it's really worth it? Doing it every few seconds as suggested seems a bit overkill.

Answer (score 1):

you can use javascript function `window.onbeforeunload` and make an ajax call to the server to save close time.

Comment: I'm not sure those events gets triggered if someone just closes the browser though.

Comment: it does(https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onbeforeunload.asp), 

but the ideal solution would be to have a an ajax call at a specific interval and save the last call's time as close time. this makes sense and possibly the best way.

Comment: That link doesn't say anything about closing the browser (ending the application).